# maven works in windows powershell and cmd, but not git bash

Tags: java, bash, git, maven

Running `mvn -v` returns this error only in git bash:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

In windows cmd:

```
C:\Users\ross>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T12:00:29-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_221, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

In git bash:

```
$ echo $PATH
... :/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin: ... :/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin: ...
```

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
```

```
$ which mvn
/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn
```

Reinstalling git bash didn't fix it

Redownloading maven didn't work either

M2_HOME, M3_HOME, MAVEN_HOME is unset

Comment: Did you set the MAVEN_HOME env variable ?

Comment: yes MAVEN_HOME is set

Comment: What happens when you go inside the maven installation folder and then do mvn -v

Comment: Remove MAVEN_HOME and only set access via PATH nothing else. Only JAVA-HOME as needed.

Comment: running it inside maven folder still gets same error

Comment: i removed MAVEN_HOME and M3_HOME, the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the **MAVEN_HOME** variable up in your environment variables